# Stain on passport page

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, philippines

Our flight will be in 2 weeks. I wont have time to get my 2 year old a new passport. We saw her passport like this after taking it from the drawer. Will it cause any issues? This is the only page affected. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this will not cause any issues.

The only reason minor damage like this to a passport could cause issues is if the immigration staff believed that the damage was as a result of an attempt to modify the passport (or the visas/stamps contained in it) in any way.

This is minor damage, and although it does appear that the staining extents to the area around the binding of the passport, it's very clear that the binding is still intact and hasn't been affected.  The page itself is blank, so clearly no visas/stamps have been affected/modified.

It is possible that the immigration staff may choose not to use this page to put a visa/stamp on, however that would only be an issue if you didn't have any additional free pages in the passport.